# registry key value read using VB SCRIPT

Tags: search, plugins, vbscript

I store a website in the registry. For example:

1. `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Default Website`
2. Key name: `Website`
3. Key value: `www.google.com/`

Then I try to create search plugin in IE.
Below is the code I use for that. It works for Google when I hard-code it,
but i want to use the registry value to set this variable.

```
<html>
<script language="VBSCRIPT">

    set parentwin = external.menuArguments
    str = trim(parentwin.document.selection.createRange().text)
    bnewwindow = parentwin.event.shiftKey

    defaultWebsite = ????????

    url = defaultWebsite +"search?q=" + escape(str)

    if(bnewwindow) then
        window.open(url)
    else
        parentwin.window.navigate(url)
    end if

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Shell` object to read and write registry values. You may get a warning in Internet Explorer when trying to instantiate an ActiveX control, since this requires access to the client PC.

```
' This uses HKCU. Change to HKLM, if you need.
Dim strKey = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Default Website\Website"

With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    defaultWebsite = .RegRead(strKey)
End With
```